# Where can I find the Rav's hesped for R Chaim Ozer Grodzinsky?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbis, mourning-aveilus, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik, speeches-addresses

I am looking for the text (in Hebrew) of R' JB Soloveitchik's hesped for R' Chaim Ozer Grozhinsky, unofficially titled "HaTzitz vehaChoshen" which was written before RJBS broke away from Agudah.

Comment: This question will be more compelling if you [edit] in why you're interested in procuring this text.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I find the question compelling even without knowing why you want the text!

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

נושא הציץ והחושן is printed inside the Sefer [דברי הגות והערכה](http://www.eliner.co.il/product.asp?productid=75).

Comment: Thanks, I just found that my local used bookstore has one. I think I'll pick it up.

Answer (score 6):

[Yalkut HaMoadim page 711](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36440&st=&pgnum=711&hilite=) & [HaPardes Number 14 page 7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=12557&st=&pgnum=7&hilite=)